# Maintaining Firebase Auth Login state across app restart in flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter

I am making an android-flutter app in which I use the firebase_auth plugin to login usesr with their phone number

Incase of login with email, we can save the credentials in sharedprefences and access it back to login again upon app restart. However in login with phone number the otp received is valid only once, how can I maintain the login state upon app restart too?

Comment: Can you post the code for how you are logging them in with phone number? If you are using Firebase Auth the user should persist between restarts.

Comment: Sorry my bad, didn't know that it worked that way , thanks for your help!

Comment: If you still can't get it to work, if you post the code you have logging in your users with phone, I may be able to help you further. But once you sign a user into FirebaseAuth, you can retrieve the current user on startup with `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` or null if no user is currently signed in. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help!! , Since i didn't find anything in the fire_auth documentation which  speaks on maintaining the user's login state , i thought that feature wasn't present in docs. Now cleared!!!

Comment: No problem, added an answer that fits the question, mind accepting it so the question is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login state for `FirebaseAuth` will persist on the device between restarts of the app. You can get and listen to the current auth state of the app using the `FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged` stream and show screens appropriately or ask for the current signed in `FirebaseUser` with `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` which will return the logged in user or null once it completes if no user is signed in.